# What are some good resources for learning about HttpContext, Request and Response?

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext

I'm trying to learn about HttpContext, Request and Response. What are some good resources? I'm especially interested in links to tutorials (basic things).

thanks
saj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to HttpContext in ASP.Net, it is a key object that exposes the underlying Request (incoming messages) and Response (outgoing message) streams. At a low level, this object is populated by IIS and the ASP.Net framework.

This means that HttpContext is available to any business object running inside of a .Net web application (not just an ASPX page, ASCX, etc).

`HttpContext.Current` provides access to Request, Response, Session, Cache, and more.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx

For HTTP basics such as Request and Response, see the links that Younes provided.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](http://www.garshol.priv.no/download/text/http-tut.html#sresp)

Or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol)

You could also try to use google.com for some searching on the net by the way.